# Javascript runtime error AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application that uses AngularJS. I am getting the following error when I run it:

> Unhandled exception at line 4, column 5 in http://localhost:49561/App/core/app.js
>
> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'usbeefConstants' is undefined

Comment: re-define "usbeefConstants" in your code, Duh !

Comment: i am also gettting this error
 JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'usbeefcorp.prefdb.prefdashboard' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: @Manmohan_singh I have already defined usbeefconstants

Comment: I am getting the following errors-
Index.html:42 GET http://localhost:49561/App/services/data.KeyItems.service.js net::ERR_ABORTED

GET http://localhost:49561/App/services/data.KeyItems.service.js 404 (Not Found)
angular.js:12477 

Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: App/KeyItems/KeyItems.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)

Comment: (anonymous) @ angular.js:12477
error @ logger.js:28
(anonymous) @ exception-handler.provider.js:69
processQueue @ angular.js:14753
(anonymous) @ angular.js:14761
$eval @ angular.js:15989
$digest @ angular.js:15800
scopePrototype.$digest @ hint.js:1495
$apply @ angular.js:16097
scopePrototype.$apply @ hint.js:1558
bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1660
invoke @ angular.js:4478
doBootstrap @ angular.js:1658
angular.resumeBootstrap @ angular.js:1686
maybeBootstrap @ hint.js:730